# Using wxPython within Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, sublimetext3

I am using Windows 10

I wish to use wxPython as a GUI for my Python3 programs. I am using SublimeText 3 to write and launch my scripts

When I launch my script from within Sublime the program runs but the wxPython window does not open. It opens as expected if I run the program from the cmd prompt.

My internet searching leads me to believe that Sublime is suppressing the window from opening and that this behavior can be changed within Sublime's settings, but I can only find instructions for Sublime Text 2.

How can I prevent Sublime Text 3 from suppressing the wxPython window?

Comment: why do you want to open the ui via sublime rather than the cmd prompt or explorer? Are you running a cmd in sublime or is it a menu option/button etc?

Comment: Are you on windows by any chance?

Comment: @OdatNurd Yes, I am using Windows 10

Comment: Can you share the build system that you're using (or the `exec` invocation)? I think the gist is you either need to use `shell_cmd` or set `shell` to `true` in the command to get `subprocess.Popen()` to do what you want (Sublime uses that to launch executables). More info is available [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/execcommand-not-displaying-win32-windows/34921?u=odatnurd).

Comment: @OdatNurd Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking or the information in the link.

Comment: @RedPython sorry for the delay in response, I caught I rather nasty cold that knocked me on my butt. How are you building/running your program from within Sublime? Just the standard `Ctrl+B` key?

Comment: @OdatNurd, sorry for the delay in responding, I have given my PC a break over the holidays.Yes I am just using the Ctrl+B key, or rather I was! I got too frustrated and got PyCharm to use as my IDE instead. I am so happy I did

Comment: ¿Are you using VirtualEnvs? If so, there is the problem. SublimeText cannot access the virtualenv and you have installed the WX in this virtual environment. Please, check [this SublimeText 3 plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, the correct extension would be *.pyw. Change the name of your WX Python script changing the extension ".py" for ".pyw" and try to run it from ST3.

Good luck.